# I want to create a matplotlib plot where the title contains the mean and standard deviation of the plots, aligned to left and right

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting two corner plots in one figure. Now I want to just extract the diagonal plots into a separate figure. The issue to directly use matplotlib is that I am not able to utilize this idea.

I want to the title to contain the mean and standard deviation of the distribution aligned to left and right with a specific colour coding. Like in the image [I want to plot something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghnPn.png)

Sometime back I recived a code from the internet in plotting like this for a corner plot, I am not able to do the same with normal plots. If there is a way where I only plot only the diagonal plots from corner plots, side by side that is also helpful

I have tried to extract the AxesSubplot but failed to plot the specific subplots.

Comment: I got the code from here for corner plots https://gist.github.com/alchzh/7f5fb3d01e53b2ad737db486d065d1a0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.